# Flot line chart tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, flot

I tried using the tooltip for flot in a separated js but it does not seem to work. (I only get to see the border)
My chart is getting data from jquery every 1000 milliseconds and then shifting the first few values if the data gets too much. Thanks in advance!

Start of java script and half of what would make up the tooltip:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let previousPoint = null, previousLabel = null;
    function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
        //console.log(contents);
        $(`<div id="tooltip">${contents}</div>`).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none',
            top: y,
            left: x,
            border: `2px solid ${color}`,
            padding: '3px',
                'font-size': '9px',
                'border-radius': '5px',
                'background-color': '#fff',
                'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
            opacity: 0.9
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
    }
```

Grid Options for chart:

```
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            borderWidth: 3,
            mouseActiveRadius: 50,
            axisMargin: 20
        }
```

Get new data:

```
function newData(){
//get data from ajax and push to dataset
            
        }
```

Function to refresh chart + draw tooltip:

```
    setInterval(function(){ 
        newData();      
        plot.setData(dataset);
        plot.setupGrid(); //only necessary if your new data will change the axes or grid
        plot.draw();
        $("#allcars").on("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
            if (item) {
                console.log(item.series.label);
                if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
                    previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
                    previousLabel = item.series.label;
                    $("#tooltip").remove();

                    var x = item.datapoint[0];
                    var y = item.datapoint[1];

                    var color = item.series.color;
                    console.log(item.pageX);
                    //console.log(item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label);               

                    showTooltip(item.pageX,
                    item.pageY,
                    color,
                            "<strong>" + item.series.label + "</strong>"  +
                            " : <strong>" + y + "</strong> ");
                }
            } else {
                $("#tooltip").remove();
                console.log("Hmm no points?");
                previousPoint = null;
            }
});
    },1000);
});//document ready
```

Comment: Hello! It would be much easier to assist / provide inputs to resolve your issue if the question is more focussed. Providing the whole code for peers to review / find faults makes it much difficult. I would ideally suggest only adding the part of code which is causing the issue (code snippet including `showTooltip` in your case).

Comment: Hello, I have made the changes that you requested, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Have you tried to move your "plothover" binding outside of your interval? Re-applying the binding every 1000 milliseconds seems excessive - you should only have to apply it once.